# CupertinoDatePicker disable hours and minutes before the current time

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

**[image: Example Image, we can't scroll to the time before current time & day]

> In the minimumDate param, we can't control the minimum time.

```
`  CupertinoDatePickerTest(                             
   onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
     print(newdate);
   },
   use24hFormat: false,
   maximumDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)),
   minimumDate:DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
   minuteInterval: 1,
   mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
   )`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minimumDate` attribute inside CupertinoDatePicker widget, the following code will disable hours and minutes before the current time:

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
      minimumDate: DateTime.now(), //Min Date time is current time
  }
```

You can use `maximumDate` attribute as well if you would like to limit the maximum date:

```
maximumDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)), //Max Date is after tomorrow
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for your comment, I've edited it =)